# How to show tooltip on click

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip

I'm trying to use [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/). My problem is that I want to show tooltip only when user clicks an `href` with a specified html inside. So I try this:

```
function help(){
    var link = document.getElementById('helps');
    if(link.innerHTML=="Open"){
        $('#helps').qtip({
           content: {
              text: 'I get shown on click'
           },
           show: {
              event: 'click'
           }
        });
    link.innerHTML = "Close";
    }else{
        link.innerHTML="Open";
    }
}
<a href="javascript:help()" id="helps">Open</a>
```

My problem is that when I click, text becomes `Close` but tooltip doesn't show. When I click again text becomes `Open` and I see tooltip. What can I do?

Comment: Why do you mix plain JS with jQuery? No need to use things like getElementById when you have jQuery. Besides that, `href="javascript:..."` is bad; use `onclick` instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thinks you could use:

```
$('#helps').qtip({
  content: {
     text: 'I get shown on click'
});
```

is the best way to have classic tooltip..

Answer (score 5):

You should initialize the `qtip` before the `onclick` handler.

```
$('#helps').qtip({
  content: {
    text: 'I get shown on click'
  },
  show: {
    event: 'click'
  }
});

function help() {
  var link = document.getElementById('helps');
  if (link.innerHTML == "Open") {
    link.innerHTML = "Close";
  } else {
    link.innerHTML = "Open";
  }
} 

< a href = "javascript:help()" id = "helps" > Open < /a>
```

Comment: He wants to show the tip only if the text of the link is "Open"

Comment: ok, this work, but when i click again qtip doesn't hide itself, what can i do?

Comment: @user1190704 hide also have a event: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
$('#helps').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'I get shown on click'
    },
    show: {
        event: 'click',
        target: $('#helps:contains("Open")')
    }
});

$('#helps').click(function() {
    if (this.innerHTML=="Open") {
        this.innerHTML = "Close";
    } else {
        this.innerHTML="Open";
    }
});

<a id="helps">Open</a>
```

Your code didn't work because you were creating the qTip on the first click! You should use the [target](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/show/) option of qTip so that the tip is shown only if your element contains the text "Open"

Comment: @user1190704 and when you click "Close"?

Comment: text will not change when i click open

Comment: @user1190704 did you take off the javascript as shown in my example?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#helps').qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'I get shown on click'
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click'
        },
        hide: {
            event: 'click'
        }
    }).click(function() {
        var _$this = $(this);

        if(_$this.html() === 'Open') {
            _$this.html('Close');
        } else {
            _$this.html('Open');
        }
    })
});
```

HTML one:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="helps">Open</a>
```

**EDIT: To hide tooltip on outer click:**

```
$(function(){           
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        var _$elm = $(e.target);
        if(_$elm.attr('id') !== 'helps') {
            $('#helps').qtip('hide');
        }               
        return false;
    });

    $('#helps').click(function() {
        var _$this = $(this);               
        if(_$this.html() === 'Open') {
            _$this.html('Close').qtip('enable');                                    
        } else {
            _$this.html('Open').qtip('disable').qtip('hide');                   
        }
    }).qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'I get shown on click'
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            when: {
                target: $('#helps:contains("Open")')
            }
        },
        hide: {
            event: 'click',
            when: {
                target: $('#helps:contains("Close")')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: when i click Close, tooltip is shown again, so it doesn't hide. I think because show and hide event have the same way to go

Comment: weird. works fine on my local test. Open shows and Close hides.

Comment: SORRY.. WORKS FINE! :) i forgot css and i don't know why now works :P GOOD THANKS!

Comment: just another things.. to hide tooltip on mouse click out? what can i do? So i have to add another event to the hide section of tooltip

Comment: Click out? You mean anywhere on the document (page)?

Answer (score 0):

or even better, use jQuery for all your JS scripts:

```
$(function(){
   $('a.tooltip').qtip(
   {
      content: 'Some basic content for the tooltip!',
      api:{
              onShow: function(){
                  $('a.tooltip').html('Close');
              },
              onHide: function(){
                  $('a.tooltip').html('Open');
              }
      },
    show: {
      when: {
            event: "click"
      }
    }
   });
});

<a class='tooltip' href='#'>Click me!!</a>
```