# Show title of an image on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, onclick

I would like to show title of an image after "click" also on mobile devices.

So far I got this, however I don't know how to display the tooltip of the image.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#imageID').on('click touchstart', function() {
        $(title).animate();
    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By title do you mean the name of the image file or the name inside the `<img>` tag or something else?

Comment: I mean title as an attribute of image

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, you want to show some toast or some little description next to the image you click on?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this and see if it helps:

[How to show tooltip on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278495/how-to-show-tooltip-on-click)

or this:

[jQueryUI tooltip Widget to show tooltip on Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753458/jqueryui-tooltip-widget-to-show-tooltip-on-click)

```
$('#imageID').click(function() {
    $('#imageID').tooltip({ items: "#imageID", content: "Displaying on click"});
    $('#imageID').tooltip("open");
});
```

If that doesn't work, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jtnmC/12/